# Stack Exchange IP is listed as malware

Tags: discussion, support

In my office any call to the chat cdn goes to `198.252.206.16` and gets blocked by our in office network.

http://www.lookip.net/whois/198.252.206.16

If you look it up on [bright cloud](http://www.brightcloud.com/tools/url-ip-lookup.php) it comes up as

> Web Attacks found

Any way we can fix that? Because right now in my office I cannot access chat because it is considered malware.

[image] [image]

Comment: How can SO fix your office's firewall?

Comment: @Servy that is not my office firewall. That is a well known IP checker that my office uses and it considers the Stack Exchange IP to be malware -- I wanted them to be aware.

Comment: A fireman can always find a fire, starts one if he has to.  I think you are supposed to click the "For Developers" link.

Comment: Technically that site is correct. Chat is run by bots ...

Comment: Is it bad that the first thing I noticed was that chrome is pestering you to update to the latest version?